# Traversing Django Foreign Keys efficiently for query sets

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm having trouble efficiently getting (second degree) related objects.
My models currently look like this

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
  from_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="sent")
  to_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="recieved")
  ...

class Account(models.Model):
  address = models.CharField(max_length=42, primary_key=True)
  ...
```

What I have been doing so far to get an aggregated list of `transaced_with` for an account is as follows:

```
accs = []
if hasattr(account, 'recieved'):
    for tx in account.recieved.all():
        acc = tx.from_account
        accs.append(acc)

if hasattr(account, 'sent'):
    for tx in account.sent.all():
        acc = tx.to_account
        accs.append(acc)
return  accs
```

This way however is very slow, so I was wondering, 
what is the the efficient way to aggregate these sort of related objects? What I want in the end is a list of `address` from the `Account`s in `accs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prefetch_related` is your friend here. Documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related